# Energy of "free" gluon

Tags: energy, photons, gluons

Does exist, if it make sense, a formula to describe the energy of a gluon, since its creation to its absorption, like the formula of Planck for the photon $\hbar\nu$?

Comment: I am not enough sure to formulate it as an answer, but to my best knowledge, yes the formula would be the same as of the photons. That is because $\hbar$ (and also $c$) are not propertis of light (or electomagnetic interfaction), they are properties of our Universe. It only can not happen because the free gluon, being also charged, would polarise other gluons from the vacuum, and the resulting mess would be strong-neutral from an external observer, and it would follow other formulas. So we could not observe a free strong charge even if we had some way to create free gluons.

Comment: read about gluons here http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/expar.html .

Comment: So, It's like to think of a box with the walls made of nucleons absorbing an emitting gluons. [Here](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/decrease-gluon-frequency-might-explain-why-nucleons-bugh-af5ie/) is an in interesting interpretation.